# How to make a cube with cylindrical ends?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, object-mode, boolean-modifier

I want to a create cylinder with 2 ends rounded.

I've tried modifiers, slicing the cylinder, join, convert to mesh.. I just can't seem to get rid of a host of problems:

- internally the finished shape contains the cylinder wall and the cube wall
- there is a weird visual artifact over the top because of duplicate faces (I think)
- I've also tried *Merge by Distance* to fix it, but it doesn't work

The object is for 3D printing, so the weird internal geometry messes things up.

What's the best, easiest way to get this done?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Make a cuboid in the dimensions you want the object to have, if you scaled it in *Object Mode* make sure afterwards you apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale*.

[image: cube dimensions]

2. Tab into *Edit Mode* and select the four edges at the ends where you want the half cylinders.

[image: select edges]

3. Start beveling the edges with the *Bevel* tool by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

[image: beveling]

4. By scrolling with the mouse wheel you can increase the number of segments. Press <kbd>C</kbd> to enable *Clamp Overlap*. With this you can extend the bevel size until it meets in the middle and it will not overlap (if it does, toggle *Clamp Overlap* off/on by pressing <kbd>C</kbd> again). When you've beveled to maximum extent, left-click to confirm the bevel.

[image: bevel max]

5. In the center where the bevel segments meet you now have doubled vertices. To get rid of them, hit <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance*.

[image: merge vertices]

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: ... if the ends are not semicircular, check 'Shape'  is set to 0.5.. I suppose.. :)

Comment: @RobinBetts Good addition. I was just assuming a newbie would have the _Bevel_ still at default settings, so the shape will be at 0.5

Comment: Hence hesitancy... Will just leave the comment.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add or use the default cube and scale on either $X$ or $Y$ axis as desired.
2. Bevel the vertical edges with <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> also to use *clamp overlap* option.
3. Use the Merge by distance operator  to remove double vertices created by the bevel operation by pressing <kbd>M</kbd>*>By distance*
4. Edge Crease the top and bottom edges with <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> +
   <kbd>E</kbd>
5. Add a Subdivision surface modifier

[image]

Comment: Oh, you were writing the same answer as me. But you should merge the doubled vertices after beveling, otherwise you might get problems with the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier or other things in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann you are right! :)  I did forget about it!

Answer (score 1):

I would try getting two halves of a cylinder (as if split down the middle and separated by a distance), and then running Bridge Edge Loops on it. Hey, you could even let it fill in for the cylinder end caps. To get two half cylinders, just create a whole one, select and delete one half (X-ray and boundary select vertices from an orthographic view should do it), and then duplicate it. You can switch to edge select and use Select Boundary Loop to get the relevant edges.

Answer (score 1):

Fully procedural you can use geometry nodes:

[image]

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to explain each step in-depth. I suggest reading up on the Box Select tool, X-Ray mode, loop cuts and the Mirror modifier in order to understand the mechanics behind these steps.

PART 1

1. Add one cube to your scene.
2. Add one cylinder to your scene.
3. Hide the cube for now (we will edit the cylinder first).
4. With the cylinder selected, switch to Edit Mode and press <kbd>NumPad 1</kbd> to enter Front View.
5. Toggle *X-Ray* vision with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.
6. Press <kbd>B</kbd> to toggle *Box Select*
7. Select and delete the vertices on the right half of the cylinder. This should leave an open, half-moon shape if viewed from the top. This is IMPORTANT as it will prevent the odd look from excess geometry that you posted about!
8. Toggle *Object mode*
9. Hide the cut-in-half cylinder

PART 2

1. Un-hide the cube
2. Select the cube
3. Toggle *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>NumPad 1</kbd> to enter *Front View*
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>R to begin a loop cut. With the yellow line oriented vertically, press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, or right click to make the cut exactly in the center of the cube.
5. Box select the vertices on the left side and delete. When viewed from the front, you should have half a cube with five (5) faces, and one (1) open face.
6. Press <kbd>NumPad 3</kbd> to go into side view. Delete this face of the half-cube. This should leave you looking through the geometry. You should have four (4) faces now.

PART 3

1. Unhide the cylinder so that you can see both objects.
2. With both objects selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to make both objects a single object that can be edited.
3. Enter edit mode in Top View (<kbd>NumPad 7</kbd>)
4. Box select the top vertex where the cube and cylinder intersect. <kbd>M</kbd> > *By Distance*.
5. Do this again for the bottom vertex
6. Select edge loop for the top open face of the cylinder (looks like a backwards *D*). <kbd>F</kbd> to fill face. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>NumPad 7</kbd> and repeat for bottom of cylinder.
7. Add mirror modifier with merge and clipping enabled.
8. Select all geometry and press <kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>X</kbd> to constrain to x axis, then -1 to move geometry -1 units.
9. Apply modifier.
10. Select edge loop in the middle of the geometry where the mirror was applied. *Delete > Dissolve Edges*.

All done!
Good Luck. Ask me if you need more help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two words. Boolean union. No artifacts since after the operation, you have only one object, not two sharing the same space. This will create a solid object.

If you want it hollow with walls of thickness t, duplicate it, scale down x,y,z so new dimensions are all 2t smaller than original, center new object into old and do a boolean difference operation. This leaves no internal structure.

Other solutions may look good on a computer screen, but they provide no options for wall thickness. (a must for 3D printing)

This page explains proper operation of boolean modifiers.
https://artisticrender.com/how-to-use-boolean-modifier-in-blender/

Comment: I was doing boolean unions and still getting artifacts and internal structures. Not sure why. Also wall thickness is something I handle in the slicing software to prepare for print, not on the model itself.

Comment: _"Other solutions may look good on a computer screen, but they provide no options for wall thickness. "_ None of all the people I know are setting the wall thickness in the model itself. They are all doing it in the printer software - there you also set if you want the model filled with a structure, how dense the structure should or if you want it completely solid for whatever reason. You only have to model wall thickness in Blender if you want a specific shape of the hollow inside.

Comment: And your scaling solution will certainly become problematic with more complex geometry, especially non-convex shapes. Since you just wrote _"scale down"_ I guess you meant the regular scaling with S, however if someone would use your method it would be better to work with the _Shrink/Fatten_ tool Alt+S in _Edit Mode_. But this will also become messy very quick with more complex shapes with the danger of overlapping geometry if you simply use 2t as scaling factor.